# adding update,delete,insert buttons to run jtable data

Tags: java, swing

I populated a jtable with database data using netbeans binding.I would Like to add delete,insert and update buttons to act on data changes in jtable and the database...How can I link the buttons to actions using gui?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? The binding, the database operations, the table data changes, the actions ... ? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement CRUD operator buttons in a similar fashion, getting use of `ActionListener`. Example for inserting a row is here:

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
       model.insertRow(0, new Object[]{"your data"});
       // The above line manipulates data only in JTable.
       // To reflect it on the database, add your SQL queries to this method.   
    }
})
```